# CorePlot with swift: there is no yAxis.majorIntervalLength

Tags: swift, graph, core-plot

Here is how my graph looks like:
[image]

I wan't the y axis to have an interval of 50 so i try doing this:

```
var axisSet: CPTXYAxisSet = CPTXYAxisSet(layer: graph.axisSet)
var y = axisSet.yAxis

y.majorIntervalLength = 50
```

But majorIntervalLength doesn't seems to exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift doesn't support `NSDecimal` values. We've made some changes to the Core Plot API, replacing `NSDecimal` with `NSDecimalNumber`. The changes are on the `release-2.0` branch and not in a release package yet. See [Core Plot issue #96](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/96) for more discussion of the issue.

Comment: Sorry i am not really good with GitHub i am using pod to download it to my project. And with pod i can only have the version 1.5.1

Comment: In your podfile: `pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git', :branch => 'release-2.0'`

Comment: Can you help me to set the plot space in swift please.
I try: var plotSpace: CPTXYPlotSpace = CPTXYPlotSpace(graph.defaultPlotSpace)

But it doesn't works it says: cannot invoke init. Before this update i was doing this: http://blog.alwold.com/2014/09/03/coreplot-nsdecimal-and-swift/ but now in the release-2 i get an error

Comment: You need to cast the value, not create a new object: `var plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as? CPTXYPlotSpace`